# AzureDev Repos, how to change target for pull request

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pull-request, azure-repos

I have created a pull request in AzureDevops Repos. Pull request is from "green_branch" into "master". I would like to change the target of this pull request from "master" to "develop" but I cannot find anywhere any "edit" button.

[image]

How can I change the target of pull request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I change the target of pull request?

You can use the option:**Change target branch** in **Pull Request -> more action button(...)**

[image]

Then you can select the target branch in the list.

[image]

Comment: @fascynacja Is there any update about this ticket? Can you confirm if the **Change target branch** option can meet your requirement?

Comment: out of curosity, are you some kind of Microsoft support?  I will check the issue of course but I have different tasks with bigger priorities and I align them myself. Do not worry for sure I will check and accept your answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I am an engineer working on azure DevOps related issues

Comment: that is very interesting to know. In fact I have many issues related with devops since I started working with it this month, also many suggestions for improvement from the usability perspective. If anyone would be interested to hear them out let me know:)